# Find the Kth smallest element in the list using Partition - Help me understand

Tags: java, algorithm, selection, quicksort

Okay I have an assignment to find the Kth smallest element in the list using several different methods....

first method is to sort the list, then return the Kth smallest element. easy, my mentality is say the list = 10 elements, sort the list in ascending order, then return the element in the 10th position

next method uses the Partition from Quicksort:

*"The second algorithm is to apply the procedure Partition used in Quicksort.  The procedure  partitions an array so that all elements smaller than some pivot item come before it in the array and all elements larger than that pivot item come after it.  The slot at which the pivot item is located is called the pivotposition.  We can solve the Selection Problem by partitioning until the pivot item is at the kth slot.  We do this by recursively partitioning the left subarray if k is less than pivotposition, and by recursively partitioning the right subarray if k is greater than pivotposition.  When k = pivotposition, we're done."*

Say I have a list of 10 items:

3 8 9 2 4 5 1 7 10 6, with 5 being the pivot.. I know I would normally would have 2 arrays

3 2 4 1  and 8 9 7 10 6

but what I don't understand is: *"We can solve the Selection Problem by partitioning until the pivot item is at the kth slot."*

what is the kth slot?  to me i keep thinking kth = the length of the array, so in this case 10.  which would have the 6 value in it, which is obviously not the lowest... and isn't correct.

can someone use this sample array and kinda just show me what this algorithm means and how it finds the kth/smallest element?  thanks

Comment: You redefined _k_ midway: first _k_ is the order of the element searched for (potentially less than the length of the array, e.g. second smallest element from 10-element array has k=2 when counting from 1) and then you say _k_ is the length of the array. kth slot is just the kth position in the array.

Comment: okay that clears up some misunderstanding.. but I'm still confused.  say for the sample array I gave, and let's say I want to find the 3rd smallest element and the pivot is always the 1st item.. i guess I don't understand how to know "what" is the 3rd smallest element until the array is fully sorted?  I think I just need someone to display it out for me so I understand...

Comment: how would i know if k is less or greater than the pivot position?

Comment: Important property on which this is based: QuickSort's partition function ensures that all elements before the pivot are smaller than or equal to pivot (though not necessarily sorted) and all elements after the pivot are larger than pivot (again, not necessarily sorted).

Comment: i mean.. i understand all that.  but I feel like I can only know what the Kth smallest element is AFTER the list is fully sorted..

Comment: For element x to be the kth smallest the following must be true: exactly k-1 elements are smaller than x. It doesn't matter whether the smaller elements are sorted or not: what matters is how many such smaller elements there are. Sorting them is just a waste of time ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have looking at the solution in a complicated way.

This is how you find the kth smallest element using QuickSort (well not entirely quicksort, I will tell why).

In quicksort you choose a random pivot element and divide the entire array into two and recursively sort the left and the right subarrays to form the entire sorted array.

In this problem you don't have to do that. All you are doing is,

> 1. Choose a random pivot element.
> 2. Divide the array with [Sub-array 1 ] Pivot [Sub-array2] where Subarray 1 has elements less than pivot and sub-array2 has elements
>      greater than pivot.
> 3. Check size of sub-array1.

```
   If it is,
        a.Greater than 'k' then your kth element lies in the first sub-array. Go recursively. Start sorting the sub-array1 alone and you can entirely discard the sub-array2 as you can be sure that 'kth' element cannot occur at a position greater than k! Repeat step-1 for the right sub-array
        b.Lesser than 'k' then your kth element lies in the second sub-array. Again do as said above. Repeat step-1 for left subarray.
        c.If the size of sub-array1 is k-1 then your pivot element must be the kth largest element in your array.Bingo! you have your 'kth' largest element in the array
```

So to address your doubt,

> Here you are not sorting the entire array but only a portion of
>   it.(even that is not true entirely. You will get it if you entirely
>   understand my above explanation.)

Answer (score 0):

In Quicksort once your pivot position is k everything to the left is less and everything to the right is greater so there's no need to continue to sort if you only needed the kth value.

Comment: i guess what i dont understand is how i would even know if the pivot position is k without fully sorting it?

Comment: from my example let's say i want the 3rd smallest element.. how would i know when my pivot position becomes "3", that that is the 3rd smallest element unless the array was fully sorted and I could check that way?  if that makes any sense..

Comment: k is given, so if your pivot position is k then you're done. you may have to sort the entire array before pivot=k if k=1 or 2 for instance and you start your quick sort in the middle.

Comment: okay i think im feeling very slow right now.. but to me this sounds like let's say k = 3, then that means the algorithm ends when the element of the pivot position is 9?

Comment: if k=3 you would return the value '3' when pivot position is 3